# PHP: a way to store the number of login attemps?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security

I want to block all the requests let's say, for 10 minutes, by IP, if there has been 5 incorrect within any 5 minute interval period.
And I'm thinking of a way to store this data in a way that would least possibly hurt the performance.

Particularly on how to design a DB table and store the data.

If I make a fixed table for IP as a primary, eg with mysql:

```
ip int(10) unsigned, primary key (ip)
attempts int(5),
lastaccess timestamp default current_timestamp
```

Then it would inadequately accumulate the attempts...

From the other hand if I log all the incorrect attempts with timestamp, eg:

```
ip int(10) unsigned,
lastaccess timestamp default current_timestamp,
primary key (ip,lastaccess)
```

And then count back in time within the 5 minutes interval, the table could potentially grow very huge with all this data and slow the system... It would also require maintenance.

So, could you advice something more convenient for me?...

Comment: how about storing them in a session variable?

Comment: Yeah, and what if the client blocks cookies?

Comment: @rsplak Anyone attempting to brute force a login will discard session cookies.

Comment: You can probably check for the client's IP. Although IP is not an unique identifier (NAT'ed clients can have the same IP), it is a possible way to block *potentially* brute-force logins.

Comment: Why not just run a cron script which empties the table at the end of each day?

Comment: Zane Bien, I was thinking of it - it is possible. I'm just curious how the other guys did.. It's quite a common task you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store the IP address and the timestamps of the last x attempts. Either in a database, a memcached type of store or possibly just a number of flat files, depending on how much traffic you anticipate.

If a database, you can easily query for something like `COUNT(timestamps) GROUP BY ip WHERE timestamp [within last 5 minutes]` and occasionally clean the database with a simple `DELETE WHERE timestamp [over 5 minutes ago]`. The cleaning could happen in a cron job or every x requests in a garbage collection kind of system.

If something like memcached or a flat file, store the timestamps in a FIFO array, i.e. a simple `array(123456..., 123456..., ...)` which you keep truncating.

Comment: This is what I did when I ran into the problem and it worked :) Did not see any significant performance impact since most users get their password right after 2 attempts at most

Comment: Well, yet it has a disadvantage - the maintenance.

Comment: I'd go further than storing the last X attempts regardless of success or failure. Storing all login attempts is a useful audit tool if you ever need it, as well as providing you with some analytics. You can still query failed attempts over a time period *when there is a failed attempt*, and use a secondary table for IP bans.

Comment: @Anon You mean the occasional `DELETE` query? I'd hardly call that a real world problem. Also, Leigh makes a good point to not remove the attempts at all.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but I wouldn't store regardless of success or failure, because the IPs are changing and that would accumulate some useless data.

Comment: If you still want statistics for failed login attempts, what you can do is create an "archive table" in which login attempts get archived, so that the main "failed login attempts" table remains small as it will be hit often.

Answer (score 1):

Just a try. I would suggest `redis` incase you are much worried about `the table could potentially grow very huge with all this data`

Generate a unique ID per user [most probably IP but consider users from same network. For ex: Users from an organization will have same IP associated with all outgoing requests even from different machine] and Use [STRING](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#strings) Data type with key as Unique ID and value as counter [stores number of attempts].

One usecase of `String` from DOC

> Use Strings as atomic counters using commands in the INCR family:
>   INCR, DECR, INCRBY.

Also String data type supports expires. So all keys that you generate will have a expiry of 5 mins which will self destruct once the time limit is reached. You can just read the counter value to determine whether to block the user or not. Now you need not worry about the number of records as the day proceeds

Redis has all your data in memory. I think you might get some performance improvement as well

Comment: I'm ignorant about redis, but I hardly see any advantage over using the sql which I'm accustomed to... Self expiry though - if that is what I'm thinking - might be a useful thing )

Comment: I See atomic INCR, reads from and writes to memory rather disk and as mentioned above expiry as advantages though ;) I'm not that much aware to comment on this features in DB :D Because they might be already available in your sql world :) Redis is blazing fast and handles concurrency amazingly